# Changing UITableViewCell Text Color with Property Value of True

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have an entity called `Item` with an attribute called `completed`.  I am displaying all `Item` objects in a custom `UITableView`. Then I have a function to set the Cell object property `completed` to `true` then set the text colour to grey.

This works fine when until I leave the view controller. How can I make all objects with the value of `true` for the property `completed` have a cell label text colour of grey when loading the table view controller ?

This is my action for changing the value and making the cell grey on action:

```
 cellCompletedAction = {(tableView: customTableView, cell: customTableViewCell) -> Void in


 let delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 let context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

 let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
 let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! customTableViewCell!;

 currentCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor

       self.itemsArray()[indexPath!.row].completed = true

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) { abort() }

 tableView.bounce(cell, duration: 0.3, bounce: 0.3, completion: nil)

    }
```

Loading data to table view:

```
 cell.textLabel?.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row].title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do a check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Something like this:

```
let cell = ... // dequeuing your cell 
let item = ... // getting the object for this cell
if item.completed == true {
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor
}
```

Comment: `if itemsArray[indexPath.row].completed == true {
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            }` - Needed to added indexPath. I was doing something very similar but after looking at your suggestion I realised where I was going wrong.

Comment: @JKSDEV Glad to hear it! Happy coding!